# c++ "fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'curl/curl.h': No such file or directory"

Tags: c++, makefile, path, include, binance

I want to use the https://github.com/tensaix2j/binacpp (a Binance c++ library) and I'm getting the same error again and again. I changed the MakeFile in the library to the correct paths but yeah... Here is my MakeFile:

```
libcurl_dir=../lib/libcurl-7.56.0
libcurl_include=${libcurl_dir}/include
libcurl_lib=${libcurl_dir}/lib

jsoncpp_dir=../lib/jsoncpp-1.8.3
jsoncpp_include=${jsoncpp_dir}/include
jsoncpp_src=${jsoncpp_dir}/src

libwebsockets_dir=../lib/libwebsockets-2.4.0
libwebsockets_include=${libwebsockets_dir}/include
libwebsockets_lib=${libwebsockets_dir}/lib

libbinacpp_dir=../lib/libbinacpp
libbinacpp_include=${libbinacpp_dir}/include
libbinacpp_lib=${libbinacpp_dir}/lib

build_dir=../lib/libbinacpp/lib
objects=$(build_dir)/jsoncpp.o $(build_dir)/binacpp_utils.o  

$(build_dir)/binacpp_logger.o $(build_dir)/binacpp.o $(build_dir)/binacpp_websocket.o

build_include=../lib/libbinacpp/include


$(build_dir)/libbinacpp.so: $(objects)
    g++ -I$(libcurl_include) -I$(jsoncpp_include) I$(libwebsockets_include)  \
    -L$(libcurl_lib) \
    -L$(libwebsockets_lib) \
    $(objects) \
    -shared \
    -lcurl -lcrypto -lwebsockets -fPIC -o $@

    # Make a new copy of the header too
    cp *.h  $(build_include)

$(build_dir)/binacpp.o: binacpp.cpp binacpp.h 
    g++ -I$(libcurl_include) -I$(jsoncpp_include) -c binacpp.cpp  -fPIC   -o $(build_dir)/binacpp.o


$(build_dir)/binacpp_websocket.o: binacpp_websocket.cpp binacpp_websocket.h 
    g++ -I$(libwebsockets_include) -I$(jsoncpp_include) -c binacpp_websocket.cpp  -fPIC   -o $(build_dir)/binacpp_websocket.o


$(build_dir)/binacpp_logger.o: binacpp_logger.cpp binacpp_logger.h 
    g++ -c binacpp_logger.cpp  -fPIC   -o $(build_dir)/binacpp_logger.o 



$(build_dir)/binacpp_utils.o: binacpp_utils.cpp binacpp_utils.h 
    g++ -c binacpp_utils.cpp -fPIC   -o $(build_dir)/binacpp_utils.o 


$(build_dir)/jsoncpp.o: $(jsoncpp_src)/jsoncpp.cpp
    g++ -I$(jsoncpp_include) -c $(jsoncpp_src)/jsoncpp.cpp -fPIC  -o  $(build_dir)/jsoncpp.o

clean:
    rm $(build_dir)/*.o
    rm $(build_dir)/*.so
```

If I'm inserting the paths like:

```
#include "../../libcurl-7.56.0/include/curl/curl.h"
```

instead of:

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
```

then it works but I cant change it for all includes.

Here's the Tree:

```
binacpp
-example
-lib
--jsoncpp-1.8.3
--libbinacpp
---include
----binacpp.h (File with include issue)
----binacpp_logger.h
----binacpp_websocket.h
----binacpp_utils.h
---lib
--libcurl-7.56.0
--(here's some other not important stuff)
-src
--MakeFile
--(here's some other not important stuff)
```

Comment: You need to add the __parent__ directory of `curl/curl.h` to your include path

Comment: Where should I add it? / How?

Comment: Compare `libcurl_dir=../lib/libcurl-7.56.0` and `#include "../../libcurl-7.56.0`?

Comment: No, because the MakeFile is in another Directory.

Comment: Do you pass a `-I` option to the compiler? This tells g++ or whatever where to look for include files.

Comment: Yes, I do. (look at the rest of the MakeFile at my Question, I added the rest)